# Facebook Messenger API

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-messenger

I am trying to build an Chat app in which I can receive & send messages to my friends from/into Facebook Messenger using APIs.

Does Facebook provide such APIs to do so?

I tried to find the way, maybe we can do it using Webhook, but I think using webhook we only can send the message. Is there any android demo for this? Please share a link if you have any.
Please suggest what I can do to achieve this if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Facebook provide such APIs to do so?

No.

There are no APIs for user-to-user communication via Messenger.

Only conversations between a user and a page can be handled via API.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: No. Facebook _wants_ people to use their product (the official Messenger app) to chat with other people, so it would be counterproductive to their interests to provide any such APIs that would allow what you want to do.